# No input promp in kdevelop python

Tags: ide, kdevelop

I'm a beginner in python using Kdev on Linux. I tried to execute this code:

nm= input('Enter your name:')

print('Welcome', nm)

Normally it should prompt something asking me the name and so on but nothing comes up:
https://pasteboard.co/JTmxsfo.png

configuration :

https://postimg.cc/k6PXVwVD